# Creating a deployment application for .NET Framework silent install across domain?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I need to deploy .NET framework 4 to all the domain User computers that run off of a server. I have created a console application that will run automatically from a Login Script that is initated when the users Log on to the domain.

The current code i have is able to link to the install file that is located on the server and run it automatically. However i am unable to run it in quiet mode i.e. using /q. Everytime the install file runs it asks for the User to prompt the install, i.e. 'Click Next' and 'Install'.

My current code looks like this (I have changed the login details and file path for security reasons. But the file is situated on a server and the login details are the main admin account) -

```
Function ConvertToSecureString(ByVal str As String)
    Dim password As New SecureString
    For Each c As Char In str.ToCharArray
        password.AppendChar(c)
    Next
    Return password
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim securePass As New Security.SecureString()
    Dim password As SecureString = ConvertToSecureString("password")
    Dim myProcess As New Process()

    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/q"
    myProcess.Start("C:\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe", "user", password, Nothing)
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
End Sub
```

To my understanding with research, the line: `myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/q"` is meant to run the install silently in the background without the user prompt. However it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that your application running as an administrator?

Comment: Isn't this a job for WSUS or Group Policy? Pretty sure there's an official WSUS package for this. Have you read the [.NET Framework Deployment Guide for Administrators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee390831(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Hi Matt, Yes the application is definatley running as an admin. thats why i am starting the process with the username, password and domain.

Comment: And hey Mark, i have read that article however the WSUS is not availabe for our use at the moment. And the article relies on Configuration Manager Console. Which we also do not have access too at the moment. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it and make a work around. i was just misplacing the line `myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/q"`

Instead i just included this into the Process.Start line and got rid of the Process Object. So now i have:

```
Process.Start("C:\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe", "/passive", "user", password, Nothing)
```

I have changed the "/q" for "/passive" because it shows a progress bar of completion.

Thanks for the advice anyway.

Greg